# SVN Repository Migration in case of server failure

Tags: eclipse, svn

My SVN server hosting my repositories for my Spring Maven project failed due to some hardware issues and unfortunately I don't have a backup. Moreover, the chances of data recovery are quite slim.

The available code is scattered among the collaborators and manual synchronization is very very tough. I configured a SVN server on one of the machines and checked in all my code to the newly created repository in hope that if my collaborators connect to the same repository location, their svn client in eclipse would be able to identify the changes and help resolve the code conflicts but sadly it didn't happen, the eclipse svn client couldn't identify the changes and was showing all the files on their workspace as outgoing.

I'm at loss right now as to what to do, if certain setting during svn server configuration allows for synchronizing the changes on the different workspaces, I would be really thankful to be pointed in the right direction.

I'm using Eclipse Indigo.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be no way to merge the changes.
Your developers have to checkout the SVN repository again and the they shoulkd copy the changed files into the checked out repo.
After that add new files and commit. Step by step you will have the latest status of the project.
Did you tried a hosted SVN solution like https://www.saas-secure.com/svn-hosting/index.html. 
This SVN hosting is more secure and high available.